# How to change a text to boxText in ExtendScript

Tags: extendscript, after-effects

How can I change a layer text to boxText in extend Script. .boxText is read only property.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It looks like it is not possible to change this on a layer. You may have to copy your text from a pointText to a boxText layer.